# What are the ? and @ signs demonstrating in this compiler error? - Visual Studio 2013 Compiler

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Take the following error:

```
Error   2   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   c:\users\james\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\PlatformGameEngine\Debug\PlatformGameEngine.exe    1   1   PlatformGameEngine
Error   1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall PlatformGameEngine::IOS::CreateWindow(class PlatformGameEngine::WindowProperties)" (?CreateWindow@IOS@PlatformGameEngine@@UAEXVWindowProperties@2@@Z)    c:\Users\James\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\PlatformGameEngine\PlatformGameEngine\App.obj  PlatformGameEngine
```

What are the ? and @ signs demonstrating in this compiler error?

Comment: I am finding that this error is not helping me much to find out where I have missed the cpp file... Any pro tips?

Comment: @Jimmyt1988: So you're really asking us how to fix your undefined reference lol. Not sure what you mean by "where". It's _nowhere_. That's the problem. You did not define `PlatformGameEngine::IOS::CreateWindow` in a C++ source file linked into your project.

Comment: My problem is i have been spoilt with c# errors.. it's going to take me some time to adjust. Thanks for your help! Ohhhhhh yesss of courseee... Thank you very much!!! Noted for future expected errors. Cheers dudette!

Comment: Obviously not a duplicate of that. Not in its current form, anyway. I did try to find a decent name mangling dupe but there wasn't one.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit: Even you obviously know it's really about the unresolved external, as made clear your earlier comment: "So you're really asking us how to fix your undefined reference".

Comment: To clarify, this question is specifically to do with the ? and @. I wanted to know what they were for as they come up alot and i never understood their meaning.

Comment: This [tool](http://d.fuqu.jp/c++filtjs/) might be helpful in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the internal, or "mangled", name for your function. It is written in an unambiguous language that your computer uses to uniquely identify the function within your program, and across any libraries that may be linked in at build-time or at run-time.

Comment: Ah i see! I was wondering if it was going to help me out more with my error, good to know what they mean finally!

Comment: Not "your computer", but compiler and linker. "Computer" (that is, CPU) couldn't care less about how functions are called, it deals with addresses.

Comment: @n0rd: The computer executes the compiler, and it executes the linker. Your pedantry is amusing but ill-placed.

Comment: Computer executes a lot of things. It does not mean it "wants" whatever those things "want". There is a clear distinction between hardware and software and for software developer it is dangerous to mix it up.

Comment: @n0rd: What the heck mate